# how to use session scoped bean in jhipster microservice architecture

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, microservices

My session scoped bean:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class AuthNodes {
    private String authNodes;
    public String getAuthNodes() {
        return authNodes;
    }
    public void setAuthNodes(String authNodes) {
        this.authNodes = authNodes;
    }
}
```

is injected in a REST controller of a JHipster generated microservice:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NodeResource {
    @Autowired
    private AuthNodes authNodes;
    ...

    @GetMapping("/nodes-and-children/{user:.+}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Node>> getFilteredNodesAndChildren(@PathVariable String user,
        @ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
        ...
        String hosts = authNodes.getAuthNodes();
        if (hosts == null) {
            authNodes.setAuthNodes("my user's authorized node names");
        }
        ...
```

but at each call the previously set value is lost and authNodes.getAuthNodes() returns null.

What is wrong?

Thanks, Mic

Comment: Microservices are supposed to be stateless so no session, this is configured in MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`.

Comment: Thanks! May I change SessionCreationPolicy? In case this is not a good practice, is there a microservice pattern to save session related data?

Comment: You can try to change it but really that's an anti pattern, why doing microservices if you must use a session that you will need to replicate to ensure some scalability?